# No unique constraint for composite foreign key, PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to relate an assosciative table with another table.

```
...

knex.schema.createTable("test", (table) => {
        table.integer("subject_id").unsigned().references("id").inTable("subject").notNullable();
        table.integer("duration_id").unsigned().references("id").inTable("duration").notNullable();
        table.unique(["subject_id", "duration_id"]);
    }),

    knex.schema.createTable("exam", (table) => {
        table.increments().notNullable();
        table.integer("subject_id").unsigned();
        table.integer("duration_id").unsigned();
        ...
        ...
        table.foreign(["subject_id", "duration_id"]).references(["subject_id", "duration_id"]).inTable("test");
    }),

...
```

throws the following error:

```
migration failed with error: alter table "exam" add constraint "exam_subject_id_duration_id_foreign" foreign key ("subject_id", "duration_id") references "test" ("subject_id", "duration_id") 
- there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "test"
```

Having unique or primary key constraint for the two columns results in the same error. Is this a knex related error?

Comment: The `UNIQUE` index is see is for `["package_id", "duration_id"]` not `["subject_id", "duration_id"]`.

Comment: Apologies, that was an editing error. ```UNIQUE``` index for ```["subject_id", "duration_id"]``` still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the foreign key constraint after the unique constraint fixed the problem. Though I don't know the exact reason.

```
...

knex.schema.createTable("test", (table) => {
        table.integer("subject_id").unsigned().notNullable();
        table.integer("duration_id").unsigned().notNullable();
        table.unique(["subject_id", "duration_id"]);
  
        table.foreign("subject_id").references("id").inTable("subject");
        table.foreign("duration_id").references("id").inTable("duration");
    }),

    knex.schema.createTable("exam", (table) => {
        table.increments().notNullable();
        table.integer("subject_id").unsigned();
        table.integer("duration_id").unsigned();
        ...
        ...
        table.foreign(["subject_id", "duration_id"]).references(["subject_id", "duration_id"]).inTable("test");
    }),

...
```